# Sql show data in tables without specifying the colum name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

So I have this code:

```
 <?php 
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 include "../includes/db_conn.php";

 $data = $_POST['tabledb'];

 $sfm = $dbm->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$data.'');
 $sfm->execute();
 $all = $sfm->fetchAll();
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <?php 
  foreach ($all as $row)
  {
  echo "<option value=\"info\">" . $row[0] . "</option>";
  }
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

oke a littel context if have a dropdown menu where you can select rows from the database, if you select a table that table is send to this page trough a ajax call. that is why I have:

```
   $data = $_POST['tabledb'];
```

in my code. now I would like to show the contents of the tables, but every table has a different amount of columus and colum names. how do I show the contents of the tables without specifying the colum name? please help.

EDIT

what I tried, I tried making it a for loop, didn't work.

EDIT 2

I wasn't clear enough, I am trying to get the same result as print_r but with a echo.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @dearsina just edited my post with what I tried, it's not much

Comment: You already use a `foreach` loop for the rows, why would you use a `for` loop for the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use implode to combine all elements for each row into a single string:

```
foreach ($all as $row)
  {
      echo ‘<option value="info">’ . implode(‘|’, $row) . ‘</option>‘;
  }
```

Or you could use use nested `foreach`:

Comment: Probably your data returned from database is duplicated. Do `var_dump($all)` to check it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the fetchAll function, it return all data inform of index and associative array.

If you want to get the data only with column name, need to use like below:

```
$all = $sfm->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this, if you just want to list the columns per table:

```
foreach($row[0] as $column => $value){
    echo "<option value=\"info\">" . $column . "</option>";
}
```

This is assuming that each table *has* data.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way to do this would be to do something like:

```
$columns = array_keys($result[0]);//this will give you an array of all the columns
    foreach($columns as $col) {
      echo <td>col</td>
     }
```

then do the values

```
foreach($result as $row) {
      echo <td>row['value1']</td>
      echo <td>row['value2']</td>
     }//or do another loop in here to through the whole array
```

then you can display it in a table format which will match what you have in your db

and for your drop down you can reuse the columns array

```
$columns = array_keys($result[0]);//this will give you an array of all the columns
foreach($columns as $col) {
  echo <option value = '.$col.'>col</option>
 }
```