# Displaying database data with for loop in php

Tags: php

So ever since this question:

[Sql show data in tables without specifying the colum name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982844/sql-show-data-in-tables-without-specifying-the-colum-name)

I have been using this to show my data:

```
foreach ($all as $row) {
    echo '<option value="info">' . implode('-', $row) . '</option>';
}
```

But now my manager came to me and said to I should do this in a for loop, but I have no idea where to start, I have tried make the for loop, but I constantly get the  Array to string conversion error my code looked something like this:

```
$array =  (array) $all;
$length = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    echo $array[$i];
}
```

EDIT

result of `print_r($all);`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [naam] => Germany [landcode] => DE [itemtarief] => [gewichttarief] => [special] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [naam] => Greece [landcode] => GR [itemtarief] => 0.422 [gewichttarief] => 2.170 [special] => 231 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [naam] => Italy [landcode] => IT [itemtarief] => [gewichttarief] => [special] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [naam] => Portugal [landcode] => PT [itemtarief] => [gewichttarief] => [special] => 238 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [naam] => Japan [landcode] => JP [itemtarief] => [gewichttarief] => [special] => 0 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 6 [naam] => Belgium [landcode] => BE [itemtarief] => [gewichttarief] => [special] => 0 ) )
```

Comment: share value of `print_r($all)` ?

Comment: you must have array inside loop use `echo implode('-',$array[$i]);`

Comment: @NikleshRaut sure

Comment: "my manager came to me and said to I should do this in a for loop"...I see no particular reason why that would be a useful change, but ok. What you had before is perfectly fine (and less verbose). Bit of a strange requirement, that.

Comment: Anyway it looks like your problem is that `$array[$i]` is itself an array, so you need to echo the individual parts of that (either using another loop, or using implode as you did before)

Comment: Read all the answers to your precedent question. You will find answers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982844/sql-show-data-in-tables-without-specifying-the-colum-name

Comment: `$array[$i]` now is what `$row` was before - you did not output that directly with echo either.

Comment: @ADyson he said it was too easy and wanted to the data in a table.

Comment: "he siad it was too easy and wanted to the data in a table.". Ah...I think maybe he intended you to replace the implode() with a loop, so you could output it into `<td>`s instead of just a simple delimited string. I would guess he didn't need you to replace the outer foreach. Although that doesn't make sense in terms of adding it inside an `<option>` tag (since you can't add a table in there) so I'm still curious what the purpose would really be. Are you meant to replace the `<option>` tags with table rows, perhaps?

Comment: @ADyson oh I forgot to mention that I use a table now <table> </table> in  here I do the foreach

Comment: You have a two-dimensional array here, “rows” and “columns” - that means you need two nested loops to access all individual values. Now with your original code, the implode statement was an “implicit” loop - it takes a whole “row” array, loops over that, and returns all elements concatenated with a - in between. If you want to output the individual values in individual table cells - then you either need to explicitly implement that second loop yourself - or you implode the items with `</td><td>` as the separator, and then output an opening `<td>` and a closing `</td>` around that …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question and also clarification in the comments, it sounds like you are now trying to build a `<table>` with rows and cells instead of a `<select>` with options.

Therefore I think you are being requested to replace the `implode()` command with a loop so you can output each field more easily in its own table cell. I don't think you need to touch the outer loop.

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ($all as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $field) {
      echo "<td>".$field."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Having said that you *could* still use implode for this in fact, if you just add a bit of markup at either end to help:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ($all as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>", $row)."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```